# Force window to focus in C#, not just making it blink orange in the taskbar

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I used the following rat's nest of code to try to keep my kiosk program's window on top and the text box within it selected:

```cs
        // Keeps the form on top and the text box selected
        private void SecurityTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uint foreThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            uint appThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
            const uint SW_SHOW = 5;
            if (foreThread != appThread)
            {
                AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, true);
                BringWindowToTop(this.Handle);
                ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_SHOW);
                AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, false);
            }
            else
            {
                BringWindowToTop(this.Handle);
                ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_SHOW);
            }
            this.TopMost = false;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Activate();
            CardTextBox.Focus();
        }
```

When I run it using the "Start Debugging" button within Visual Studio, the code works as intended and keeps the window on top, preventing the Start menu and the Win+Tab task switcher from being displayed. However, when I directly run the compiled .exe from File Explorer, it doesn't stop other programs from opening, and only causes the program to blink orange in the taskbar. I also tried `this.Activate()` and `this.Focus()`, but they didn't work either. I am on Windows 10. May someone please tell me the problem with my code? Thanks!

Edit: I think I might have "solved" the problem by clicking once on the program, then the code works, but I have yet to find a full solution. I would appreciate if someone found out a good way to keep the form on top for unattended kiosk use.

Comment: does it also do this when you run it as administrator?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Unfortunately yes! The only way to get it to run as intended is to run it from within the IDE instead of from File Explorer.